# Linux 2.6.36.4, GCC 4.7.2, getting lots of "variable set but not used" warnings

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile the Linux kernel 2.6.36.4 on Linux Mint 14 running a 3.5 kernel by default. Using gcc version 4.7.2. Tried googling it, but didn't quite work out.
The warning is:

```
warning: variable ‘gfp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

I have tons of these warnings all over the compilation. The compilation does NOT fail anywhere at all. And the worst part is the compiled kernel doesn't boot successfully either.

Do I need to set any more gcc options? Or should I simply ignore it?

Note: I am working on virtualbox. The stock kernel works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

"Variable set but not used" warnings are informational.

According to [the official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), `-Wunused-but-set-variable` controls the behavior of:

> Warn[ing] whenever a local variable is assigned to, but otherwise unused (aside from its declaration). This warning is enabled by `-Wall`.

The purpose is to catch situations where the programmer assigns a value to a variable and then never does anything more with it. The kernel is fairly special in that in the deep trenches of low-level operating system programming, even I can imagine situations where doing something like that can be perfectly legitimate and even *necessary* to achieve the result you are after.

If the variable assignment statement is truly unneeded, the compiler is likely to optimize it away.

Bottom line, unless you are the developer, it should be safe to ignore this class of warnings. If you are the developer, you should consider whether the assignment is necessary. If portability to non-GCC compilers is not a priority, consider adding the `__attribute__((unused))` to the declaration to suppress the warning for that variable; see also [Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes).

Comment: Hi, I am aware of the purpose of Warnings. I myself am a developer, and my compiled kernel does not work. That is why I was curious whether this warning has anything to do with it, since it comes with a rather serious kernel variable name, gfp. I don't think modifying the attributes of a kernel variable would be such a good idea. I may be wrong though.

Comment: There is a million ways how a Linux kernel can build successfully but fail to boot. If your real problem isn't the warning, but rather the failure to boot, you should post a question focusing on that, and include pertient information for addressing that problem, rather than focusing on something that may or may not have anything at all to do with your actual problem.

Comment: 2.6.36.4 is dated 2011-02-17; the odds are good that if it had a crippling bug related to assigned-but-unread variables, even if only in some oddball configuration, someone would have spotted (and fixed) it by now. Such bugs aren't like e.g. timing issues, which can lay dormant for years or decades.

Answer (score 1):

> Or should I simply ignore it?

Unused variables *could* be an indication of a coding mistake.  If you are satisfied this is not the case and want to suppress the warning for a particular variable, you can use a [(GCC specific) `__attribute__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) tag, e.g.:

```
/* Unused parameter (in definition, not declaration): */
void somefunc (int x __attribute__ ((unused))) {
    [...]
}

/* Unused variable. */
int x __attribute__ ((unused));
/* But set... */
x = 1;
```

The first case is not unusual if you are fulfilling an API -- e.g., writing a callback where you ignore the parameter, but must match the callback signature.  The second case seems a little oxymoronic, but might be useful temporarily if you've declared and set something you haven't used yet and don't want to be distracted by the warning, etc.

This is probably better than turning off `-Wunused-parameter` and/or `-Wunused-but-set-variable`.

Comment: Is it safe to modify kernel variables like this? If it were any regular code I would've done that.

Comment: Ah -- I kind of missed the point that you were just compiling the kernel and not hacking on it or writing a module.  No, don't bother to change the source.  It's not unusual to see bunches of warnings like this, it just means someone did not bother to suppress them. If the kernel compiled okay but won't boot, it is most likely a misconfiguration (e.g., whoops, forgot filesystem support).  If it at least reports something before it fails, you should post a question with that stuff in it.

Comment: There's always the matter of memory pointers declared `volatile`. Without having looked, I can easily imagine there are a number of those in certain parts of the kernel source code, as it would probably be one reasonably natural way to speak to the hardware on some architectures. Writing to such a variable to control the behavior of a hardware device might not require a value to be read back, which just might trigger these sorts of warnings, and they cannot (easily or at all) be removed by the programmer or optimized away by the compiler.